# Finding natural numbers having n Trailing Zeroes in Factorial

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, factorial, trailing

I need help with the following problem.

Given an integer `m`, I need to find the number of positive integers `n` and the integers, such that the *factorial* of `n` ends with *exactly* `m` *zeroes*.

I wrote this code it *works fine* and i get the right output, but it take way *too much time* as the numbers increase.

```
a = input()

while a:
 x = []
 m, n, fact, c, j = input(), 0, 1, 0, 0
 z = 10*m
 t = 10**m

 while z - 1:
  fact = 1
  n = n + 1   

  for i in range(1, n + 1):
     fact = fact * i

  if fact % t == 0 and ((fact / t) % 10) != 0:
     x.append(int(n))
     c = c + 1

  z = z - 1

 for p in range(c):
  print x[p],

 a -= 1
 print c
```

Could someone suggest me a *more efficient way* to do this. Presently, it takes **30 seconds** for a test case asking for numbers with `250` trailing zeros in its factorial.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get number of trailing zeroes of `n!` *efficiently* you can put

```
def zeroes(value):
    result = 0;

    d = 5;

    while (d <= value): 
        result += value // d; # integer division
        d *= 5;

    return result; 

...

# 305: 1234! has exactly 305 trailing zeroes 
print zeroes(1234)
```

In order to solve the problem (what numbers have `n` trailing zeroes in `n!`) you can use these facts:

- number of zeroes is a *monotonous* function: `f(x + a) >= f(x)` if `a >= 0`.
- if `f(x) = y` then `x <= y * 5` (we count only `5` factors).
- if `f(x) = y` then `x >= y * 4` (let me leave this for you to prove)

Then implement *binary search* (on *monotonous* function).

E.g. in case of `250` zeroes we have the initial range to test `[4*250..5*250] == [1000..1250]`. Binary search narrows the range down into `[1005..1009]`.

**1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009** are all numbers such that they have exactly `250` trainling zeroes in factorial

**Edit** I hope I don't spoil the fun if I (after *2* years) prove the *last conjecture* (see comments below):

Each `5**n` within facrtorial when multiplied by `2**n` produces `10**n` and thus `n` zeroes; that's why `f(x)` is

```
f(x) = [x / 5] + [x / 25] + [x / 125] + ... + [x / 5**n] + ...
```

where `[...]` stands for *floor* or *integer part* (e.g. `[3.1415926] == 3`). Let's perform easy manipulations:

```
f(x) = [x / 5] + [x / 25] + [x / 125] + ... + [x / 5**n] + ... <= # removing [...]
        x / 5  +  x / 25  +  x / 125  + ... +  x / 5**n  + ... =
        x * (1/5 + 1/25 + 1/125 + ... + 1/5**n + ...) =
        x * (1/5 * 1/(1 - 1/5)) =
        x * 1/5 * 5/4 =
        x / 4
```

So far so good

```
 f(x) <= x / 4
```

Or if `y = f(x)` then `x >= 4 * y` Q.E.D.

Comment: can you give me any hint why `x >= y * 4`  ? can't prove it... @Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: @fardinabir: I've edited the answer, I've added the proof

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Shouldn't the inequality be x <= (y+1)*5. Like, y = [x / 5] + [x / 25] + [x / 125] + ... + [x / 5**n] + .... Now, thus, y >= [x / 5]. But, we can't directly say y >= x/5. For x<25. Thus, shouldn't the inequality be y >= x/5 - 1. This should cover all the cases. Or, we can change the inequality depending on the number. Like for bigger numbers your inequality holds good, and for smaller the one I suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Focus on the number of 2s and 5s that makes up a number. e.g. 150 is made up of 2*3*5*5, there 1 pair of 2&5 so there's one trailing zero. Each time you increase the tested number, try figuring out how much 2 and 5s are in the number. From that, adding up previous results you can easily know how much zeros its factorial contains.

For example, 15!=15*...*5*4*3*2*1, starting from 2:

```
Number   2s  5s  trailing zeros of factorial
2        1   0   0
3        1   0   0
4        2   0   0
5        2   1   1
6        3   1   1
...
10       5   2   2
...
15       7   3   3
..
24      12   6   6
25      12   8   8   <- 25 counts for two 5-s: 25 == 5 * 5 == 5**2
26      13   8   8 
..
```

Refer to Peter de Rivaz's and Dmitry Bychenko's comments, they have got some good advices.

Comment: As you will always have more 2's than 5's, you can probably just count the 5's and simplify

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I'll refer to your comment in my answer.

Comment: Do not forget to count `25` *twice*, `125` *three times*, in general case `5**n` - `n` times

Comment: Test: `1005!..1009!` have `250` trailing zeroes

Comment: appreciate the quick response, (fact/t)%10, i have included the 5s and 2s as 10=5*2, this saved me from checking for 5^n,...but the factorial part is making program slow.