# Finding smallest number N, having k trailing zeroes in factorial of N

Tags: factorial, number-theory

I got a problem about finding the smallest N, where N! contains exactly k trailing zeros.

I've got an idea of finding it through binary search from here -  [Finding natural numbers having n Trailing Zeroes in Factorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911621/finding-natural-numbers-having-n-trailing-zeroes-in-factorial) .

Is it possible to calculate it without binary search, using any formula or some iterations?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula that the number of times `p` divides `n!` is:

```
k = floor(n/p) + floor(n/p^2) + floor(n/p^3) + ...
```

Combining this with the fact that the number of trailing zeros is exactly equal to the number of times `5` evenly divides it (each zero corresponds to a `2` and `5` pair, but given `2` is less than `5`, we'll always have more `2`s than `5`s, and thus be constrained by our `5`s).

With some algebra, and applying the formula for an infinite geometric series, we can get a very (very!) close lower bound on `n`. We then just increment `n` by `5` as much as necessary get the actual result. In practice, this ends up being 1-2 increments for `k` in the lower thousands, so its fairly negligible.

Full code below:

```py
def count_div5(n):
    result = 0
    pow5 = 5
    while pow5 <= n:
        result += n // pow5
        pow5 *= 5
    return result

    
def n_from_fact_zeros(k):
    n = round(4*k)
    n += -n % 5
    
    while count_div5(n) < k:
        n += 5
    return n
```